# Kubernetes internal wildcard DNS record

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to create a wildcard DNS record that maps to a virtual IP inside my k8s cluster. This is because I want requests from my pods to any subdomain of a given name to map to a specific set of endpoints. I.e. requests from:

```
something.my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
something-else.my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
any-old-thing-my-pod-came-up-with.my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

to all resolve to the same virtual IP, and therefore to the same *cluster* (i.e. I would like these requests to be routed to endpoints in the same way a service does).

I've seen some other solutions that involve creating and modifying the cluster DNS service (i.e. kube-dns or CoreDNS) config. This doesn't work for me- the main reason I'm asking this question is to achieve declarative config.

What I've tried:

- Service `.metadata.name: '*.my-service'`. Failed because `'*.my-service'` is not a valid service name.
- Service `.spec.ports.name: '*'`. Not a valid port name.

Not an option:

- Ingress. I cannot expose these services to the wider internet.
- Pod hostname/subdomain. AFAIK DNS entries created by pod hostname/subdomain will not have a virtual IP that may resolve to any of a number of pods. (Quoting from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields) "DNS serves an A record at that name, pointing to the Pod’s IP."

Answer (score 0):

wild card dns is not supported for kubernetes services. what you can do is front the service with an ingress controller. with ingress you can use wild card dns. refer the below PR

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/29204

Comment: I did consider using an ingress, I should've probably mentioned in my question. But exposing these internal services externally is not allowable. Thank you for your answer- I'll update the question to reflect that this is not viable for me.

Comment: Hi could you please elaborate. Could you please take a look for "[Pod’s hostname and subdomain fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)"?

Comment: I assume you meant me. I've expanded the question to explain why the pod hostname/subdomain fields won't work for me. Thanks for the link, unfortunately I'd already found that one, and probably should've already mentioned it in the question.